# How do leading key=value pairs on shell commands work? Why are they not an error?

Tags: shell, environment-variables

```
(my_virtualenv)my_pc:~/path$ ASDF='asdf' python
...
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['ASDF']
'asdf'
```

So how does this work? Why doesn't the interpreter look for the `ASDF` command, and report an error if it doesn't find it?

Comment: This will work for every program, not just for Python

Comment: FYI, this isn't a behavior of your terminal, but of the shell running in the terminal. You'd have the exact same behavior from that shell running in any other terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because leading `var=value` pairs are recognized as command-specific environment variable names as part of the standard for shells compatible with POSIX sh.

From [2.10.2 ("Shell Grammar Rules")](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_10_02) of the Shell Command Language specification:

> `7.` [Assignment preceding command name]
>
> `7.a.` [When the first word]
>
> If the TOKEN does not contain the character '=', rule 1 is applied. Otherwise, 7b shall be applied.
>
> `7.b.` [Not the first word]
>
> If the TOKEN contains the equal sign character:
>
> - If it begins with '=', the token WORD shall be returned.
> - **If all the characters preceding '=' form a valid name** (see the Base Definitions volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001, Section 3.230, Name), **the token ASSIGNMENT_WORD shall be returned.** (Quoted characters cannot participate in forming a valid name.)
> - Otherwise, it is unspecified whether it is ASSIGNMENT_WORD or WORD that is returned.
>
> **Assignment to the NAME shall occur as specified in Simple Commands.**

From [2.9.1 ("Simple Commands")](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_01) of the Shell Command Language specification:

> If no command name results, variable assignments shall affect the current execution environment. Otherwise, **the variable assignments shall be exported for the execution environment of the command and shall not affect the current execution environment** (except for special built-ins). [...]

Emphasis added.